# How to positively charge an object with a power source?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

How do you positively charge something consistently? By what mechanism could this be achieved?

Comment: Simple. Bring a negatively charged object nearer to your object so that [electrostatic induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction#Charging_an_object_by_induction) could be possible. BTW, Hi Pmeister, Welcome to Physics.SE. I think I've seen a [similar question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38402) ;-)

Comment: Thanks Crazy Buddy. I checked out the other post you suggested. I couldn't quite figure out how I could physically use a power source to continuously positively charge an object. I am a novice so you may have to really dumb it down for me!

Comment: Well, your post doesn't say a word about *"continuously" or "constantly"* - which is the necessary keyword. Does that "consistent" actually means "continuous" here ?? (If so, pardon me for that) :D

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yeah thats what I was attempting to say. I am trying to basically use a power source to consistently induce a positive charge in an object, but Im not sure how to go about setting that up physically.

Comment: I think I still can't catch up. Induction is good even if there's a constant power source.

Comment: I'm thinking of bombarding the object. To negatively charge it, use an [electron gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_gun). To positively charge the object, use an [ion gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_source).

Comment: Can you induce a positive static charge on an object using only a DC current? Or can I literally hook up the positive end of a battery to an object in conjunction with other pieces of the setup to do it? If so what would be the other pieces of the set up in that situation? Sorry if this is a dumb question, bear with me, I am here to ask questions from experts because I clearly am not one!

Comment: I answer below with the simplest set up, the duplicate reference has all the more complicated ones. Every battery has a + and a -. If you attach a metal plate on the + it will become positively charged. If what you want to charge is not metallic, use the methods described in the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a simple [capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) across a  (DC) battery: one plate will be positive the other negative. There will be a transient current until the plates are saturated.

[image: plates]  [image: charges]
–