# What do we mean by this statement : "some positive charge is put on a metal piece"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

What do we mean by this statement : "some positive charge is put on a metal piece" ?

(I know it will be distributed on the surface of the metal piece, if metal is isolated.)

Electrons are negatively charged particles.
Protons are positively charged particles.

I am sure we are not putting protons on metal piece!! Then what we are putting as positive charge?

Comment: Generally this is meant to say that we are taking away electrons. Then the net charge on the metal plate will be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Its not like putting any charge but simply making that metal piece charge to be positive.
It can be done simply charging metal piece by :

1. Friction
2. Induction
3. Conduction
4. or by the Removal of a Charge (Grounding)

While seeing question I come to know that you already asked one question and there also you asked the same question in this link at last line:

[What happens when a conducting plate is grounded?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/183368/what-happens-when-a-conducting-plate-is-grounded)

If you'll see the answer which is provided by [Hritik Narayan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/63547/hritik-narayan) that is :

> Also, I think the answers here would help for (2) [How to make
>   something charged using electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38397/how-to-make-something-charged-using-electricity)

Which is correct and it can clear your doubt.

Comment: Are 3rd method (conduction) and 4th method grounding same ? When we ground metal piece, electrons are conducted through wire, from piece to the earth.

Comment: @atom There are much like same but if you notice that the process of grounding refers to the 'removal of charge' whereas the process of conduction is 'sharing or transfer of electrons'   . I guess you got your answer :)